# Can the Dread Helm make additional eyes (not the wearer's) that are attached to it glow red as well?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

The description of the [*dread helm*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/dread-helm) says (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 137):

> This fearsome steel helm makes your eyes glow red while you wear it.

I am currently playing a character that ritually cuts out the eyes of enemies we kill. Our group had the idea of what would happen if he started attaching those eyes to the *dread helm* he's wearing.

If additional eyes were attached to the *dread helm*, would it make those glow red as well? Or only the wearer's own eyes?

Comment: Yes, but so will too much booze. Your point being..? :-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### The helm makes *your* eyes glow; somebody else's eyes are not your eyes

Strictly speaking, whether or not somebody else's eyes that you've effectively stolen count as your own eyes is going to be up to the GM. But I believe the extreme majority of people would interpret this as meaning your very own eyes; the ones that are (hopefully) inside your own head.

---

#### Rule of Fun/Cool

*However*, if *I* were the GM I would rule that all of them turn red because that is just plain cool and it is the type of fun and primarily cosmetic change that I encourage my players to seek out.

Comment: What do you mean? He took them, surely they’re now *his* eyes?

Comment: @DaleM Well, he *stole* the eyes. So while he might be in possession of the eyes, he is not the rightful owner.

Comment: @Philipp possession is nine tenths of the law. Anyway I’m sure the McBeth witches’ “eye of newt” was their eye of newt now - I mean the newt wasn’t using it.

Comment: @DaleM If possession is 9/10s of the law, obviously they should roll a d10 for each set of eyes attached and on a 1-9 they glow red.

Comment: What about if you have one or more slaves, or perhaps followers who have given themselves to you in an act of devotion?  Would the helm make *their* eyes glow?

Comment: Ooooh oh, or in an odinesque deal you give one of your eyes to some Fae being as part of a deal... would it still glow red?

Comment: @Philipp well, technically the previous owners are dead at that point, so wouldn't that mean the eyes were unowned and thus simply claimed as loot? Same as picking up an item from the ground.

Answer (score 10):

### Only the eyes in your body count

Whether additional eyes glow depends on how you interpret "your" in the sentence.

DnD was written using common language. Most people when they read "makes your eyes glow red while you wear it" wouldn't think that it could be used for interplanar communication. If the helm was intended to refer to eyes that belong to you in a capitalistic sense then it would have said so clearly. Since it didn't we can understand that "your eyes" only refers to your bodily eyes.

**With common language things only do what they obviously say they do.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122531/discussion-on-answer-by-odo-can-the-dread-helm-make-additional-eyes-not-the-wea).